# Sort file beginning at a certain line

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I'd like to be able to sort a file but only at a certain line and below.  From the manual sort isn't able to parse content so I'll need a second utility to do this.  read? or awk possibly?  Here's the file I'd like to be able to sort:

```
tar --exclude-from=$EXCLUDE_FILE --exclude=$BACKDEST/$PC-* \
-cvpzf $BACKDEST/$BACKUPNAME.tar.gz \
/etc/X11/xorg.conf \
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.1 \
/etc/fonts/conf.avail.1 \
/etc/fonts/conf.avail/60-liberation.conf \
```

So for this case, I'd like to begin sorting on line three.  I'm thinking I'm going to have to do a function to be able to do this something like

```
cat backup.sh | while read LINE; do echo $LINE | sort; done
```

Pretty new to this and the script looks like it's missing something.  Also, not sure how to begin at a certain line number.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
(head -n 2 backup.sh; tail -n +3 backup.sh | sort) > backup-sorted.sh
```

You may have to fixup the last line of the input... it probably doesn't have the trailing \ for the line continuation, so you might have a broken 'backup-sorted.sh' if you just do the above.

You might want to consider using tar's --files-from (or -T) option, and having the sorted list of files in a data file instead of the script itself.

Comment: Yeah, though after re-reading the question, you'd want -n +3.  But I suspect that using --files-from would be a better approach for you.

Comment: I discovered this can be trimmed down a bit following Steve's suggestion and doing: 'tail -n +3 backup.sh | sort -o backup.sh'. Doing --files-from=... is a lot better option though, wasn't aware that was available, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

clumsy way:

```
len=$(cat FILE | wc -l)
sortable_len=$((len-3))

head -3 FILE > OUT
tail -$sortable_len FILE | sort >> OUT
```

I'm sure someone will post an elegant 1-liner shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the lines excluding the (2 lines) header, just for view.

```
cat file.txt | awk '{if (NR < 3) print $0 > "/dev/stderr"; else print $0}' | sort
```

Sort the lines excluding the (2 lines) headers and send the output to another file.

Method #1:

```
cat file.txt | awk '{if (NR < 3) print $0 > "/dev/stderr"; else print $0}' 2> file_sorted.txt | sort >> file_sorted.txt
```

Method #2:

```
cat file.txt | awk '{if (NR < 3) print $0 > "file_sorted.txt"; else print $0}' | sort >> file_sorted.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
(read line; echo "$line"; sort) < file.txt
```

It takes one line and echoes it, then sorts the rest. You can also:

```
file.txt | (read line; echo "$line"; sort)
```

For two lines, just repeat the read and echo:

```
(read line; echo "$line"; read line; echo "$line"; sort) < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ if ( NR > 2 ) { print $0 } }' file.txt | sort
```

NR is a built-in `awk` variable and contains the current record/line number. It starts at 1.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a solution to the original question since it skips the 1st two lines altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Extending [Vigneswaran R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278335/sort-file-beginning-at-a-certain-line/23465800#23465800)'s answer using `awk`:

using `tty` to get your current terminals' stdin file, print the first three lines directly to you terminal (no it won't run the input) within awk and pipe the rest to sort.

```
tty
>/dev/pts/3

cat file.txt | awk '{if (NR < 3) print $0 > "/dev/pts/3"; else print $0}' | sort
```